# Mathematical measure of whether something's on schedule or not?

Tags: standard-deviation, calendar-computations

Say I decide to jog everyday for 1 km. I start jogging and I keep a log of which days I'm jogging on. Now after a couple of months, I notice in my logbook that although I jogged for 1 km on most days, there were days when I didn't jog at all. Also, on some days I jogged for 2 or 3 km. Now I want to **quantify** how much I was on my determined schedule (of jogging 1 km per day). Which mathematical measure would be applicable here?

I think calculating standard deviation is the key here, but I'm not sure how to calculate it in this context. Any answer with example data and calculations will be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you compute the average km per day?
$$
\text{average}=\frac{\text{total km in month}}{\text{days in month}}.
$$ If the average is close to $1$km, you are close to your determined schedule.

Comment: Average is too crude. I'm looking for a more rigorous quantification. @Fimpellizieri's answer is a great start - possibly what I was looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard deviation refers to a probability distribution, but of course we don't actually know what's the probability distribution for the $\text{km}$ you'll jog on a given.
We can naively estimate this distribution as follows.

Let $N$ be your sample size, meaning your log has $N$ entries (or days). Here, the $i$-th entry is the number $x_i$ of $\text{km}$ you ran on day $i$, including days when you ran no $\text{km}$ at all $($in this case, $x_i=0)$. To each value $v$ on your log we'll associate the probability

$$p_v=\frac1N\cdot\#\{\text{entries with value $v$ in your log}\}.$$

The expected value of the number of $\text{km}$ ran on a given day will then be

$$\mu=\sum_v\,v\cdot p_v$$

and the standard deviation will be

$$\sigma=\sqrt{\sum_v^{}\,p_v\cdot {(v-\mu)}^2}$$

---

**Example:** Suppose your $2$-month log has $61$ days, with the following distribution:

- $9$ days with $0$ $\text{km}$ jogs
- $38$ days with $1$ $\text{km}$ jogs
- $9$ days with $2$ $\text{km}$ jogs
- $5$ days with $3$ $\text{km}$ jogs

Then our set of values $v$ is $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and we have

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
p_0=\frac{9}{61}&&p_1=\frac{38}{61}&&
p_2=\frac{9}{61}&&p_3=\frac{5}{61}
\end{array}
$$

Our mean jog has a length of

$$\mu=0\cdot\frac{9}{61}+1\cdot\frac{38}{61}+2\cdot\frac{9}{61}+3\cdot\frac{5}{61}=\frac{71}{61}\simeq 1.164$$

kilometres, and our standard deviation will hence be

\begin{align}
\sigma
&=\sqrt{
\frac{9}{61}\cdot{\left(0-\frac{71}{61}\right)}^2+
\frac{38}{61}\cdot{\left(1-\frac{71}{61}\right)}^2+
\frac{9}{61}\cdot{\left(2-\frac{71}{61}\right)}^2+
\frac{5}{61}\cdot{\left(3-\frac{71}{61}\right)}^2}\\
&=\sqrt{
\frac{9\cdot 71^2}{61^3}+
\frac{38\cdot 10^2}{61^3}+
\frac{9\cdot 51^2}{61^3}+
\frac{5\cdot 112^2}{61^3}}\\
&=\sqrt{
\frac{45369+3800+23409+62720}{61^3}
}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{135298}{61^3}}\simeq 0.772
\end{align}

kilometres.

---

The standard deviation is a measure of how closely you follow your schedule in the following sense:
the closer your values $v$ are to the mean $\mu$, the smaller the standard deviation $\sigma$.
For instance, if you had run $1$ $\text{km}$ every day, then $\sigma=0$.

The thing is, the standard deviation in principle does not really care that your schedule is $1$ $\text{km}$ per day...
If you had run $0$ $\text{km}$ every day, or $3$ $\text{km}$ day, then you'd also have $\sigma = 0$.

With this in mind, what you *can* do is take a page from least squares and calculate how far from your scheduled $1$ $\text{km}$ your jogs are, on average.
In symbols, we'll be looking at

$$\epsilon=\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\,{\left(x_i-1\right)}^2}.$$

Grouping the $x_i$ by their values $v$, it turns out that

$$\epsilon=\sqrt{\sum_v^{}\,p_v\cdot {(v-1)}^2}.$$

Looks familiar, huh?
It's like the calculation for $\sigma$, except here we're forcing $\mu=1$ (our scheduled value).
Using the numbers for our previous example, we'd get

\begin{align}
\epsilon
&=\sqrt{
\frac{9}{61}\cdot{\left(0-1\right)}^2+
\frac{38}{61}\cdot{\left(1-1\right)}^2+
\frac{9}{61}\cdot{\left(2-1\right)}^2+
\frac{5}{61}\cdot{\left(3-1\right)}^2}\\
&=\sqrt{
\frac{9\cdot 1}{61}+
\frac{38\cdot 0}{61}+
\frac{9\cdot 1}{61}+
\frac{5\cdot 4}{61}}\\
&=\sqrt{
\frac{38}{61}} \simeq 0.789
\end{align}

Now, $\epsilon$ measures how closely you follow your schedule in the following sense:
the closer your values $v$ are to your intended schedule value $($ $1$ in this case$)$, the smaller the standard deviation $\sigma$.
If you had run $1$ $\text{km}$ every day, you'd still get $\epsilon=0$.

Moreover, we don't run into the same problems as we did with $\sigma$ before.
If you had run $n$ $\text{km}$ every day, then you'd have $\epsilon=|n-1|$ -- you can't get better than this for these cases!

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to ignore the first half of the answer because it's not telling me the right thing (if I'd run 3km every day then 0 isn't correct quantification for this context). The second half of the answer is clever. I seek 3 clarifications.. 1. Why'd you say e=n-1 at the end? If I run 2km every day we get 1.41, and not 1.. 2. Can we generalise this for continuous values? I.e., No of km run each day need not be just a few discrete values.. 3. How would you mathematically state this number. That 'you were 78.9% on your schedule'?

Comment: $(1)$: If you had run $n$ $\text{km}$ every day, then your only value $v$ would be $n$ and you'd have $p_n=1$. The calculation would reduce to

$$\sqrt{1\,\cdot\,{(n-1)}^2}=|n-1|.$$

$(2)$: This already applies to non-integer values. I used integer values merely for the sake of example. Any nonnegative real number makes sense for the $x_i$ $($and hence for $v)$.

$${}$$

$(3)$: I don't understand your question here. The number is $\epsilon$... If you want to give it a fancy name say something like 'Your standard square deviation from schedule is $\epsilon$'.

Comment: (1) & (2) are clear now, thanks. I asked (3) since I'm not sure if it's legal to force the mean as 1km in the standard deviation calculation. I'm basically asking for the interpretation of this variable we defined. Is it okay to still call it 'standard deviation'? Also, is this kinda forced mean done elsewhere in maths?

Comment: Yes, it's okay to perform the calculation for $\epsilon$ as it was written, but it is not okay to call it 'standard deviation'. 'Standard deviation' is a well defined term with an understood meaning, and would reference the calculation done for $\sigma$. The interpretation is that $\epsilon$ $($respectively $\sigma)$ measures how much, on average, your jog length deviates from your **intended** (respectively **mean**) jog length.
$${}$$This kind of calculation is performed frequently in the context of least squares and even $p$-norms $($with $p=2$ in our case$)$.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a ton!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help.